# Perl -M flag, uninitialized value?

Tags: perl, powershell, initialization, comparison, numeric

I've written a PowerShell script that generates 100 files with random time stamps:

```
$date_min   =   get-date -year 1989 -month 7 -day 4
$date_max   =   get-date

for( $i = 0;  $i -le 100;  $i++ )
{
    $file   =   $i.ToString() + ".txt"
    echo ">=|" > $file

    $a  =   get-item $file
    $time = new-object datetime( get-random -min $date_min.ticks -max $date_max.ticks)

    $a.CreationTime     =   $time
    $a.LastWriteTime    =   $time
    $a.LastAccessTime   =   $time
}
```

Using Perl, I'm trying to sort these files based off of the last modified time, like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir     =   "TEST_DIR";
my @files;     

opendir( DIR , $dir ) or die $!;

# Grab all the files in a directory
while( my $file = readdir(DIR) )
{   
    next if(-d $file);  # If the "file" is actually a directory, skip it
    push( @files , $file );        
}

my @sorted_files    =   sort { -M $b <=> -M $a } @files;    # Sort files from oldest to newest
```

However, when I run my code I get:

> Use of uninitialized value in numeric comparison (<=>) at .\dir.pl line 31.

Now, if I try this code against files that were not randomly generated with my powershell script, it works just fine.  I'm having a very difficult time figuring out why it doesn't work with these randomly generated files.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is the `readdir(DIR)`. This produces a list of files relative to the directory specified. Try adding the `$dir` to the files first:

```
sort { -M $b <=> -M $a } map { "$dir\\$_" } @files
```

This also means your attempt to filter out directories is wrong. You can combine all the calls together like this:

```
my @sorted_files = sort { -M $b <=> -M $a }
    grep { ! -d $_ }        # Removes directories
        map { "$dir\\$_" }  # Adds full path
            readdir(DIR);   # Read entire directory content at once
```

Comment: or  `sort { -M "$dir/$b" <=> -M "$dir/$a" } @files`

Comment: ST would be useful here. `my @sorted = map $_->[0], sort { $b->[1] <=> $a->[1] } map [ $_, -M $_ ], ...;`